# How to find positive integers where the multiplicative modular inverse is equal to itself for mod n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function, project-euler

This a question sparked from [Project Euler Questio](http://projecteuler.net/problem=451)n. I really devoted so much time to search an efficient solution however no output. What are some possibles theorems or formulas that are useful in that problem? I thought Euler's Totient function should have some role but no way to come up for me. Would you enlight me a bit if you know some trick?

I recently realized that for the formula $f(N)= x$ such that  $x^2 \equiv 1$ $ mod(N)$ then if $N=2^e \mid e>2$ then we have recursive formula like $f(2^e)=2*f(2^{(e-2)})-1$. However there other numbers that are not exact composites of 2.

For example $f(8)=5$ and $f(16)=(f(8)*2)-1$ and $f(32)=(f(16)*2)-1$

Comment: So, you're looking for numbers $m$ such that
$$
n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n
$$
is that it?

Comment: Search for "quadratic residues"

Comment: @Arthur yeap your formulation is right

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$, I take it you are looking for $x$ such that
$$
x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.
$$

1. First use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to reduce to the case when $n = p^{e}$ is a power of a prime $p$.
2. If $p = 2$, you only have $x = 1$ for $2^{e} = 2$, $x = \pm 1$ if $2^{e} = 4$, and [in general $4$ solutions when $2^{e} \ge 8$, and these are $\pm 1, \pm 1 + 2^{e-1}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_2).
3. If $p$ is odd, there are the two solutions $\pm 1$.

Comment: How could I define any $n$ as a composite number of a single prime $p^e$. I also have some other values for $n$ that are not possibly factorized as you proposed at first argument.

Comment: By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic you know that $n$ factorizes uniquely as $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem (step 1 in Andreas' answer) allows you to treat the cases modulo $p_i^{e_i}$ separately.